# Regular expression variable that matches alpha characters only

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this non-functioning javascript:

```
function test(id) {
    if (id.match('^(.+?)#')) {
        alert(RegExp.$1);   
    }
}

test('test#f');   // should alert 'test'
test('tes4t#f');  // should not alert
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r7mky2y9/1/

I only want to match `a-zA-Z` characters that appear before the `#`. I tried adjusting the regexp so it was `(.+?)[a-zA-Z]` but I have a feeling that is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

That's regex 101 for you:

```
var m = id.match(/^([a-zA-Z]+)#/);
if (m) alert(m[1]);
```

In Javascript, regular expressions are defined between slashes.

Also, the lazy quantifier is no use here. I haven't tested performances, but there shouldn't be any difference.

Finally, take advantage of the return value of `match`, which returns and array with the complete mathed expression, followed by the captured groups.

Comment: I have seen regular expressions work without the slashes, are they mandatory or do they serve some sort of purpose?

Comment: @OP Maybe you've seen them in PHP, not in Javascript.

Comment: The expression `[a-zA-Z]` is known as a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function test(id) {
  var rmatch = /^([a-zA-Z]+?)#/;
  var match = id.match(rmatch);
  if (match) {
    alert(match[1]);
  }
}
```

Explanation:

```
function test(id) {
  var rmatch = /^([a-zA-Z]+?)#/; // This constructs a regex, notice it is NOT a string literal
  // Gets the match followed by the various capture groups, or null if no match was found
  var match = id.match(rmatch);
  if (match) {
    // match[1] is the first capture group, alert that
    alert(match[1]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(id.match(/^([a-zA-Z]+)#/))`.

Updated my answer, since `match`needs a regex argument, not a string.

Furthermore, `id.match(/^([A-z]+)#/)` matches `^test`for some reason. Why?

Comment: This was downvoted - what is incorrect with this expression? I tested it and it seems to check out okay?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function test(id) {
  var regex = /([a-z]+)#/i,
      group = regex.exec(id);
  if (group && group[1]) {
    alert(group[1]);
  }
}
```

It's saying to capture (with the parens) a group of one or more letters ([a-z]+), followed by a hash, and make matches case-insensitive (because of the i at the end).